# How to prevent updating a single attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models, controllers, before-save

When a form is submitted, how to prevent a single attribute from being updated in Rails? All other attributes should be updated.

Is it `before_save`, `attr_reader` or some other way?

If using `before_save`, how to access to the attributes hash?

Rails 3.0.7

Comment: Have you looked into attr_accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out **[`attr_protected`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected)**.

```
Class YourModel << ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_protected :the_one_column, as: :update

  # ...
end
```

Now as part of a call to `update_attributes`, you'd specify the `:update` role, for example

```
klass = YourModel.find(some_id)
klass.update_attributes(params[:your_model], as: :update)
```

If `:the_one_column` is set in `params` passed to `update_attributes`, it will throw an error.

As @Beerlington mentioned in his comment to your Question, you should also check out **[attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible)**. It's generally better to spend the 30 minutes going through all models of your application white-listing attributes using `attr_accessible` than it is to blacklist specific attributes with `attr_protected`.

Comment: what happens when creating new one?

Comment: `.create()` or `.new()` + `.save()` will throw the same error if `:the_one_column` is included.

Comment: Read about **[mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)** in rails, specifically about 'roles'. If you wanted `:the_one_column` to be allowed through mass assignment when creating a model instance but not when updating, you'd specify a separate 'create' from the default.

Answer (score 2):

Other option is simply doing this in your controller:

```
klass.update_attributes( params[:your_model].except(:attributes_to_avoid) )
```