# Limiting which user attributes can be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not want to allow the user to update their `:name`. I found this [question for Rails version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020296/how-to-prevent-updating-a-single-attribute-in-rails/12024592#12024592) but the answer does not work for me. I am using Rails 4. I might just have the wrong syntax. I couldn't get `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` to work. Only:  `@user.update_attributes(user_params)`. I am not including `:name` on my edit form, but my understanding (??) is that a user could still pass it through the browser themselves and with my current code they could change `:name`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      flash[:danger] = "Profile update Unsuccessful"
      redirect_to 'edit'
    end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way to assure users won't tamper with your business rules.
As you're already using Rails 4, you can take advantage of strong parameters to deny access to the `:name` attribute.

You can have different sets of rules for each controller action:

```
def create_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

def update_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

@user.create(create_user_params)
@user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
```

drying up:

```
def allowed_update_attrs
 [:email, :email_confirmation, :password, :password_confirmation]
end

def allowed_create_attrs
 allowed_update_attrs + [:name]
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user)
end

@user.create user_params.permit(*allowed_create_attrs)
@user.update_attributes user_params.permit(*allowed_update_attrs)
```

There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing like tapping into already permitted attributes, but this way seemed simpler.

Comment: I want them to be able to create `:name` initially with `new/create`... i just don't want them to be able to `update/edit` their `:name` after that.

Comment: Thanks this work correctly. Does anyone know if `.except` as linked to in the question still works with Rails 4?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss I've just realized `Parameters` inherits from `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so my previous comment was wrong. `.except` should work.